# Accessing and updating an attribute that is qualified with a namespace using Groovy XMLParser

Tags: xml, groovy

```
<msg:Request xmlns:msg="urn:some.namespace">
  <msg:Metadata msg:RequestGuid=""/>
</msg:Request>
```

I intend to read this static XML template and update the msg:RequestGuid using XMLParser.

How do I do this?

What I have isn't working, fails with 
java.lang.NullPointerException: groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: value for class: java.lang.String

```
def Request = new XmlParser().parseText(Utils.readFile(this.class, "templates/rq.xml"));
Node requestGuid = RetrieveRequest.attribute(msg.RequestGuid);
requestGuid.value = UUID.randomUUID();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe there is an easier way to get to the attribute, but i have not seen it

```groovy
 def request = new XmlParser().parseText('''\
 <msg:Request xmlns:msg="urn:some.namespace">
 <msg:Metadata msg:RequestGuid=""/>
 </msg:Request>''')

 // the ns, be sure to copy the uri properly
 def msg = new groovy.xml.Namespace('urn:some.namespace', 'msg')

 def metadata = request[msg.Metadata][0]

 // only good for reading
 println metadata.attribute(msg.RequestGuid) // ""

 // writing must be done via the map of attributes
 metadata.attributes()[msg.RequestGuid] = 'theuid'

 println metadata.attribute(msg.RequestGuid) // theuid
 new XmlNodePrinter().print(request)
 //<msg:Request xmlns:msg="urn:some.namespace">
 //  <msg:Metadata msg:RequestGuid="theuid"/>
 //</msg:Request>
```

Comment: Awesome, this was driving me crazy trying to figure out @cfrick